# No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen ruby and csv

Tags: ruby, csv

First of all I would like to say that I'm new to Ruby and if I'm not able to give you a good picture of what I'm trying to solve, that is the reason.

I'm trying to convert URLs into images and I've looked around for answers but I can't seem to find an answer that works for me. The file has around 70,000+ links and I'm also trying to name these at the same time. I'm using ruby 2.3.0 if that is relevant.

Code --

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'tempfile'
require 'uri'
require 'csv'

def downloadFile(path,url)
 begin
  open(path, "wb+") do |file|
   file << open(url).read
  end
  return true
rescue
  return false
  end
end

puts Dir.pwd
CSV.foreach("C/Users/b40ssr/RubymineProjects/Bygma/convert/konvertera.CSV",     headers:true) do |row|
 downloadFile(row[0], row[1])
end
```

So the error that I'm getting is
C:/Ruby23/lib/ruby/2.3.0/csv.rb:1265:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C/Users/b40ssr/RubymineProjects/Bygma/convert/konvertera.CSV (Errno::ENOENT)

I understand that there is something wrong with the directory but I cant seem to figure out what it is.

Comment: Your error tells you what's causing it. There's no file or directory with the name you specified, so it can't open anything.

Comment: But when I click the dir in the folder it's the same as the one in the code except for the .CSV ending. C:\Users\b40ssr\RubymineProjects\Bygma\convert

Comment: Are you sure that the file is actually a .csv file then? Try going to that location on the command line and entering (on Windows) `dir` or (on Unix systems) `ls`

Comment: When I do that the csv file opens up

Comment: ...Right, I just noticed that in your filepath in `CSV.foreach`, you wrote `C\ ` instead of `C:\ `. Try changing that and seeing if it fixes anything.

Comment: Thanks :), it ran the code. But did not change anything though.

Comment: At this point, you need to debug it yourself -- Stack Overflow is for helping with specific problems, not doing your debugging for you. :)

Comment: Well thank you for the help. Appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can use relative path or just use "C:/"

Second, You are trying to open each row of CSV file ??

CSV.foreach("C/Users/b40ssr/RubymineProjects/Bygma/convert/konvertera.CSV"). This will iterate over each rows in CSV file.
Do you want to open each CSV file inside a directory ??