# Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am doing a project with Ruby on Rails, trying to build an E-commerce grocery shop and so have created some data to work without of my `db/seed.rb` file.

I created a CSV file which contains information like product, SKU, category, a site name, price, etc. and then put the following code into my `seed.rb` file:

```
require 'csv'
CSV.foreach(Rails.root.join("db/seeds_data/Store.csv"), headers: true) do |row|
  Store.find_or_create_by(upc: row[0], article_name: row[1], product_category_name: row[2],
  super_product_category_name: row[3], category_code: row[4], category_name: row[5],
  trading_area_name: row[6], ranged_articles_tw: row[7], site_name: row[8], price: row[9])
end
```

I then try to run, `rails db:seed`, and it returns this error:

```
Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /home/ec2-user/environment/grocerystore/db/seeds_data/store.csv
/home/ec2-user/environment/grocerystore/db/seeds.rb:2:in `<main>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Is the name of your file `Store.csv` or `store.csv`? In your `seed.rb`, you specify `Store.csv`, but your error messages says `store.csv`.

Comment: Check this one out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37984543/no-such-file-or-directory-rb-sysopen-ruby-and-csv

Comment: yes you are right there was an error here so i  renamed the CSV file to store.csv to match the seed.rb: now produces a name error 'NameError: uninitialized constant Store'

Comment: Do you have a file `app/models/store.rb`? What is the content of this file?